# Check if appointment time fits users working time with SQL - Wrong proposal during night

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I defined hours where an employee is working aka working hours, e.g.

```
$start = "09:00:00";
$end = "18:00:00";
```

A user can now select an appointment, and the query should validate it, e.g.

```
$appointment_start = "09:00:00";
$appointment_end = "10:00:00";
```

My SQL query should now check if the employee is working at that specific time. If that is the case, propose this appointment to the user. This is how I do it:

```
...
AND w.start <= '$appointment_start' 
AND w.end >= '$appointment_end';
```

There seems to be a problem during night when the day changes, e.g. when `start is 23:00:00` and `end is 00:30:00`. This should not be a valid appointment time, but my query proposes it:

```
start substr: 23:00:00 || end substr: 00:00:00 
start substr: 23:30:00 || end substr: 00:30:00
```

How do I have to change the `WHERE` statement of my SQL query to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `datetime` rather than just a time to avoid this issue altogether.

Or you could do something like:

```
    AND (( w.start < w.end
           AND w.start <= '$appointment_start'
           AND w.end >= '$appointment_end') OR
         ( w.start > w.end
           AND w.start >= '$appointment_start'
           AND w.end <= '$appointment_end' ) )
```

Basically, you invert your comparison operators when start happens after end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use a `datetime` you could massage your values.

```
$appointment_end = ($appointment_end < $appointment_start) ? $appointment_end + [24hours] : $appointment_end;
$end  = ($end  < $start) ? $end  + [24hours] : $end;
```

Basically if the end time is less than the start time, assume it's the next day and add 24 hours, then do the check as normal.  (not sure of the syntax in php to add the [24hours])